# Add h-card or vcard to contacts (Ideally with Javascript)

Tags: javascript, vcf-vcard, microformats

I am in the process of building a website where a many pages will have a single listing in both h-card and vcard microformats. Is there a way to add (perhaps a JavaScript) link/button to trigger a device (including desktops ideally) to add the marked up information to the users address book?

Answer (score 1):

the closest thing that i can think of is microsoft's Oomph, which at first was IE only, then redone to be cross-browser, but last i can remember they shut it down, with it still needing some work...so even if you use this, it won't be a final answer: you're probably going to have to do a little tweaking to it:
http://timkadlec.com/2008/10/microsoft-gives-microformats-a-little-oomph/